I got an issue when interact with anchor project using coral-xyz/anchor
I try to run this function in client, but I got an issue with it.
    try {
      const provider = getProvider();
      const program = new Program(idl, provider);
      const accounts = {
        accounts: {
          campaign: publicKey,
          user: provider.wallet.publicKey,
          systemProgram: SystemProgram.programId
        }
      }
      await program.methods.donate(new BN(0.5) * web3.LAMPORTS_PER_SOL, accounts).rpc();
      console.log("Donated some money to: ", publicKey.toString());
      getCampaign();
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error: ", error);
    }
  };```

browser throw a catch error, told me that "Error:  Error: provided too many arguments 0,[object Object],[object Object] to instruction donate expecting: amount". Although, I ensure that I passed right args. Here is **donate** function in Rust.

```pub fn donate(ctx: Context<Donate>, amount: u64) -> ProgramResult {
        let ix = transfer(
            &ctx.accounts.user.key(),
            &ctx.accounts.campaign.key(),
            amount,
        );
        let _ = invoke(
            &ix,
            &[
                ctx.accounts.user.to_account_info(),
                ctx.accounts.campaign.to_account_info(),
            ],
        );
        (&mut ctx.accounts.campaign).amount_donated += amount;
        Ok(())
    }```

and derive account struct.

```#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Donate<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub campaign: Account<'info, Campaign>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub user: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}```


You should convert to this
new BN(0.5 * web3.LAMPORTS_PER_SOL)
await program.methods.donate(new BN(0.5 * web3.LAMPORTS_PER_SOL)).accounts({ campaign: publicKey, user: provider.wallet.publicKey, systemProgram: SystemProgram.programId }).rpc();

Thank you. I resolved it, coral-xyz/anchor @0.3.0
